# Bash & 'su' script giving an error "standard in must be a tty"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Folks, I'm having an issue with a **bash** script which runs a particular command as a **different user**.

The background: Running on a Linux box (CentOS), the script is quite simple, it's starting the [hudson-ci](http://hudson-ci.org/) application.

```
declare -r HOME=/home/hudson
declare -r RUNAS=hudson
declare -r HOME=/home/hudson
declare -r LOG=hudson.log
declare -r PID=hudson.pid
declare -r BINARY=hudson.war

su - ${RUNAS} -c "nohup java -jar ${HOME}/${BINARY} >> ${HOME}/${LOG} 2>&1; echo $! > ${HOME}/${PID}" &
```

This is the abridged version of the script, when run, the script exits with **"standard in must be a tty"**. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? I've tried [Dr Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=standard+in+must+be+a+tty) and all the advice hasn't helped thus far.

Other reference:
[Mandriva Linux 'su' bug](http://lists.mandriva.com/bugs/2010-02/msg01260.php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your /etc/sudoers file, try commenting out the line that says "Defaults requiretty". There are security implications of doing so, so you might want to instead add this line below:

```
Defaults:[username] !requiretty
```

Be sure to use the visudo command to edit this file, rather than a regular text editor.

Comment: You can also make security admins happier by limiting the scope of your removal of restrictions by specifying the user who can issue a command with no tty. see: http://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user

Comment: Neither of these worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't /etc/sudoers apply to the `sudo` tool, not coreutils `su`?

Comment: Why must you use `visudo` ? Please expand

Comment: @8bitjunkie Thats why to use `visudo`  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/why-do-we-need-to-use-visudo-instead-of-directly-modifying-the-sudoers-file