# script calling script as other user

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, daemon

Using CentOs, I want to run a script as user 'training' as a system service. I use daemontools to monitor the process, which needs a launcher script that is run as root:

1. :

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exec >> /var/log/training_service.log 2>&1
   setuidgid training training_command
   ```

   This last line is not good enough since for training_command, we need environment for training user to be set.
2. :

   ```
   su - training -c 'training_command'
   ```

   gives '`standard in must be tty`' as su making sure tty is present to potentially accept password.
   I know I could make this disappear by modifying /etc/sudoers a la
   [Bash & 'su' script giving an error "standard in must be a tty"](https://superuser.com/questions/119376/bash-su-script-giving-an-error-standard-in-must-be-a-tty) but i am reluctant and unsure of consequences.
3. :

   ```
   runuser - training -c 'training_command'
   ```

   gives `runuser: cannot set groups: Connection refused`. I found no sense or resolution to this message.
4. :

   ssh -p100 training@localhost 'source $HOME/.bashrc; training_command'

I get `Host key verification failed.` (the host key IS in known_hosts, etc).

**Note: all of 2,3,4 work as they should if I run the wrapper script from a root shell.** problems only occur if the system service monitor (daemontools) launches it (no tty terminal I guess).

I am stuck. Is this something so hard to achieve?

I appreciate all insight and guidance to best practice.

Comment: how about setuid/setgid flags?

Comment: @Sampo would you mind elaborating? as I said setuidgid not enough cos I need env. or you mean that flag on runuser?

Comment: I republished this as http://serverfault.com/questions/397031/run-script-as-another-user-from-a-root-script-with-no-tty-stdin

Answer (score 2):

Source the environment in your startup script if mugen kenichi's solution is not an option. I have some startup scripts that use mugen's approach and others that source the environment directly in the script. It's often simply a matter of preference. Sourcing the environment directly in the startup script is more transparent to other users who might edit the script (or you 6 months from now).

As my environment is made up of alot of conditionals it's easier to be implicit. Here's the first few lines from one of my startup scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /my/tools/environment/apps/apps_rc
. /my/tools/environment/functions/common.bash
```

Once this is done use **su** as normal to start the process as the user in question.

Here's a sample of how I start similar processes using `su`.

```
su -l $USER -c "nohup $APP_PATH" >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

As an option you can also look at the ***daemonize*** package. I use it quite a bit as well.

#### Finally...

As from your question it appears as though you may want to run the script as a priveleged user you may actually need to **set the setuid bit on the script** to allow it to run as root by a normal use. This can have a security implication so know what you're doing when you do this.

Comment: but as i said su called from script gives an error

Comment: you should share how you're using it. I use `su` all the time in this context.

Comment: thanks for your attention. the script as in the OP is the /service/training/run executable, and i switch on the service with svc -u /service/training. supervise then launches the run script which fails since su needs tty stdin which is missing, so i get 'standard in must be tty' in my /var/log/training_service.log (and of course my training command is not run. hope this explains the context.

Comment: Your question has about 4 separate unrelated problems that need to be solved separately. The ssh error, group error have nothing to do with your question and you should read the man pages or post separate questions.

Comment: dear mogga, I got one problem that needs to be solved: run a script as another user (using that users environment, from a root script with no tty standard in). I just presented my 4 different attempts at solving it that all fail.

Comment: mogga, the ssh manual sheds no light on why host key verfication fails when supervise call my script, but runs perfectly when i call it from the terminal. thanks for your help

Comment: there are many reasons why a key might fail... 1) it's not a matching key  2) the permissions on the key file are incorrect  3) the permissions on the .ssh directory are incorrect  4) your .ssh/config file is not correctly configured 5) the system sshd config ... these are just 5 possible places to look for problems

Comment: all of your 1-5 are ruled out by the fact that the command runs when the script called from a root terminal. but fails if called by daemontools without a tty. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disable the `requiretty` setting in `/etc/sudoers` for `root`. Add the following line via `visudo`:

```
Defaults:root !requiretty
```

You will also need the following line in `/etc/sudoers` so `root` can do everything (this should be enabled by default, but check to be sure):

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then you can do the following:

```
sudo -u training /path/to/training_command
```

Comment: This answer has been perpetuated all over questions like this but it is completely and utterly ineffective.